# Word Count Program in C is not counting correctly

Tags: c, shell, word-count

Like the title says im writing a Word Count clone Program in C, but is not counting correctly in one of the cases.
I have .txt file and the program works fine but if i use the following command

```
linux>./wordcountclone < file.txt
```

it only counts half the words.
Am i doing anything wrong?
if i use for example

```
linux>./wordcountclone file.txt
```

or

```
linux>./wordcountclone -l -d file.txt
```

works fine.
Here goes the function im using

```
void fileO(FILE * name, int car, int word, int lin, int dig){
    int c , nl, np, nc, nd, state;
    state = OUT;
    nl = nc = nd = 0;
    np = -1;
    c = fgetc(name);
    while (c != EOF){
        c = fgetc(name);
        nc++;
    if(nc > INT_MAX)
        return;
    if (c == '\n')
        nl++;
    if (c > 47 && c < 58)
        nd++;
    if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
        state = OUT;
    if (state == OUT) {
        state = IN;
        np++;
    }
}


    if(lin !=0)
        printf("lines %d ", nl);    
    if(word != 0)
        printf("words %d ", np);
    if(dig !=0)
        printf("digits %d ", nd);
    if(car != 0)
        printf("chars %d ", nc);
    printf("\n");
```

}

and the .txt file that i am using has the following text

```
the cat sat on the mat
the dog jumped over the moon
```

Comment: Consistent and readable indentation is important when posting code here. As it is, you've made it hard to read.

Comment: How are you running it when it works fine?

Comment: Could you add your sample txt?

Comment: And is it consistently wrong with other text files? Maybe an EOF character it the middle of this one?

Comment: The bets way is to debug the code with your sample data to see what is going wrong

Answer (score 2):

At least 2 problems here:

- You always skip the first char doing `c = fgetc(name);` twice in a row - one before `while` and then inside the loop.
- The `state` logic is incorrect - if you run this on a file containing only whitespace it'll still count words.

Also, a couple of suggestions:

- instead of `if (c > 47 && c < 58)` you could do `if ('0' <= c && c <= '9')` or use `isdigit()`
- use `isspace()` to check for whitespace

Comment: still isn't working, i think its when i use the redirect (<) in the terminal (linux>./wordcountclone < file.txt ) that its giving me the problem

Comment: When you do redirection, you get the input via ```stdin```. Make sure you pass that to your function as your input stream.

Comment: Sorry but i'm not understanding, where do i pass that? in the FILE * name ?

Comment: Yes. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29180833/linux-redirection-to-c-program-file-reading

Comment: in addition to the suggestions, it is impossible for this condition to be true: `if(nc > INT_MAX)`; that should probably be a check for `EOF` (as above, in the loop condition) and because of the `nc++;` prior to it, `EOF` is counted as a character... This all seems to lead me to believe the OP is writing in a language and/or hacking at code he/she doesn't understand and might need a good book to cement that understanding.